# SHELL - AND operation within IF statement

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, ksh

Assuming thoses functions :

```
return_0() {
   return 0
}

return_1() {
   return 1
}
```

Then the following code :

```
if return_0; then
   echo "we're in" # this will be displayed
fi

if return_1; then
   echo "we aren't" # this won't be displayed
fi

if return_0 -a return_1; then
   echo "and here we're in again" # will be displayed - Why ?
fi
```

Why I am getting into the last `if`statement ? 
Aren't we supposed to be out of the condition with those `0` and `1` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-a` is one of the options of the `test` command (which is also implemented by `[` and `[[`). So you can't just use `-a` by itself. You probably want to use `&&`, which is a control operator token for an `AND` list.

```
if return_0 && return_1; then ...
```

You *can* use `-a` to tell `test` to "and" two different `test` expressions, like

```
if test -r /file -a -x /file; then
    echo 'file is readable and executable'
fi
```

But this is equivalent to

```
if [ -r /file -a -x /file ]; then ...
```

which may be more readable because the brackets make the *test* part of the expression clearer.

See the Bash Reference Manual for further information on...

- `&&`, see [lists](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Lists)
- `if` statements and the various `test` commands and keywords, see [conditional constructs](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs)

Answer (score 4):

When you execute

```
if return_0 -a return_1; then
   echo "and here we're in again" # will be displayed - Why ?
fi
```

You execute the line `return_0 -a return_1`. This actually means that you pass `-a` and `return_1` as arguments to `return_0`. If you want to have an **and** operation, you should make use of the `&&` syntax.

```
if return_0 && return_1; then
   echo "and here we're in again" # will be displayed - Why ?
fi
```

The useful information to understand this is:

> AND and OR lists are sequences of one of more pipelines separated by the `&&` and `||` control operators, respectively.  AND and OR lists are executed with left associativity.  An AND list has the form
>
> ```
> command1 && command2
> ```
>
> `command2` is executed if, and only if, `command1` returns an exit status of zero.
>
> An OR list has the form
>
> ```
> command1 || command2
> ```
>
> `command2` is executed if and only if `command1` returns a non-zero exit status.  The return status of AND and OR lists is the exit status of the last command executed in the list.